# GraphQL alias/change name of input type field name

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I need to have a GraphQL input type defined a certain way:

```
input MyInput {
    package: boolean
}
```

A service already sends the data as `package`, and I cannot change how that service sends the request.

Using Java, however, I cannot use the keyword `package` as a field name. I tried using `@JsonProperty("package") Boolean pckge;` in my Java class, but the value is always null.

I can use that when the field name is defined in a type definition:

```
type MyType {
    package: Boolean
}
```

But I need to use:

```
@SchemaMapping(typeName = "MyType", field = "package")
public Boolean getPackage(@NonNull MyType myType) {
    return myType.pckge();
}
```

However, that does not work for input types and I get an error when I try:

```
You have asked for named type 'MyType' but it's not GraphQLFieldsContainer but rather a 'graphql.schema.GraphQLInputObjectType'
```

Is there a way to make an alias/mapping for the field name in the input type?

I am using Java 21 and Spring Boot 3.2.2 (with spring-boot-starter-graphql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use `DataFetchingEnvironment` in the Controller to get the request and map the variable to the "Java" variable name.

For example:

```
@MutationMapping
public MyType updateMyType(@Argument MyType myType, DataFetchingEnvironment env) {
   var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   var myTypeMap = mapper.convertValue(env.getArguments().get("myType"), Map.class);
   var packge = myTypeMap.get("package");
   // Continue with request now that we have the value
}
```